# Generic Composables

Tags: kotlin, generics, android-jetpack-compose

I wrote a simple wrapper for the `Text` composable to use a string resource.

```kotlin
@Composable
fun Text(@StringRes id: Int) = Text (stringResource(id))
```

Next I did the same for bold text.

```kotlin
val bold = TextStyle(fontWeight = FontWeight(600))

@Composable
fun Bold (text: String) = Text (style = bold, text = text)

@Composable
fun Bold (@StringRes id: Int) = Bold (stringResource(id))
```

Now I realized that the two composables using the string resource look quite the same. So I tried to make them generic. But this does not work:

```kotlin
@Composable
fun <C: Composable>WithStrRes (@StringRes id: Int) = C(stringResource(id))
```

The error is:

> Type parameter C cannot be called as function

How to fix this?

---

Using function references does not work either. When I try to replace the redundant definitions with a builder

```kotlin
// @Composable
// fun Text(@StringRes id: Int) = Text (stringResource(id))
// @Composable
// fun Bold (@StringRes id: Int) = Bold (stringResource(id))

fun withStrRes(composable: (String) -> Unit): (Int) -> Unit =
    @Composable
    fun (@StringRes id: Int) {
        composable(stringResource(id))
    }

val Text: (id: Int) -> Unit = withStrRes(::Text)
val Bold: (id: Int) -> Unit = withStrRes(::Bold)
```

I get the error

> Function References of @Composable functions are not currently supported

Answer (score 1):

The thing you are trying to achieve is not possible in kotlin. You are trying to give type parameter `C` extending `Composable`.
Since compose is based on kotlin functions (Not the classes) , inheritance is the not possible for functions.
Also function cannot be passed as type parameter in kotlin. Only classes can be added as type parameters.

Here the `Composable` is an `annotation class`. If you define like below only Composable class can be passed as type. Annotation classes are final and it is not possible to create another class extending Composable class.

```
@Composable
fun <C: Composable>WithStrRes (@StringRes id: Int)
```

So your definition only allows to call function like below which is unwanted in compose.

```
  @Preview(showBackground = true)
    @Composable
    fun DefaultPreview() {
        WithStrRes<Composable>(id = R.string.app_name) 
      //Here type param should be Composable class itself. This is not required 
    }
```

The way to achieve reusable composables is by following way definining higher order functions of `@Composable` type as reuse below.

Here second parameter accepts only functions which is annotated with `@Composable`

**Generic Composable:**

```
@Composable
fun Bold(text: String) = Text(style = bold, text = text)

@Composable
fun Bold(@StringRes id: Int) = Bold(stringResource(id))

@Composable
fun WithStrRes(@StringRes id: Int, C: @Composable (id: Int) -> Unit) {
    C(id)
}
```

**Usage:**

```
 @Preview(showBackground = true)
    @Composable
    fun DefaultPreview() {
        StackOverflowAndroidTheme {
            Greeting("Android")
        }
        WithStrRes(id = R.string.app_name) {
            Bold(id = it)
        }
    }
```